# Linker error in OpenCV C++ binaries after anaconda reinstall

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, anaconda

I reinstalled python anaconda and now my previously compiled C++ OpenCV apps are no longer working.

When I try to run my binaries I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libhdf5.101.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hdf.4.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
[1]    5054 abort      ./test
```

As far as I understand this, this means an opencv library tries to use another dynamic hdf5 library at runtime but the linker can't find it.

Comment: `otool -l /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hdf.4.0.0.dylib` to list properties, including what the @rpath(s) are set to.  Then see if hdf5 is still there.  If you upgrade hdf5 just make sure your newer version is still api/abi compatible with the opencv_hdf module in use.

Comment: thanks that was helpful. it gives me two LC_RPATHs. I believe I understand the problem now. One rpath points to my old anaconda (python) installation, but I have installed a newer version to different path. So normally the solution would be to change this rpath with install_name_tool, right? The problem is the newer anaconda version also comes with a different libhdf5 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The cause:**

As suggested I used `otool -l /usr/local/lib/libopencv_hdf.4.0.0.dylib` and analyzed its output. There I found that the last `LC_RPATH` pointed to my old anaconda installation, in my case `~/anaconda3/lib`. So it seams that OpenCV, the way I've originally built it, relies on the HDF5 dylib of my anaconda installation. Even the C++ binaries rely on my python anaconda installation for this.
I previously only searched for the missing library under `/usr/local/lib` which didn't yield any results. When I removed my old anaconda version and installed a newer one, I not only removed the library but anaconda now installs into a different path as well (now `~/opt/anaconda` instead of `~/anaconda`).

**The solution:**

I guess the obvious solution would have been to change the @rpath of `libopencv_hdf.4.0.0.dylib` to point to the new installation. However, the newer ancaonda version comes with a newer libhdf5 version and thus a different filename.

Instead I created a softlink in one of the @rpath locations to point to the new installation of the library.

Both versions work. So either:

`ln -s ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/libhdf5.103.dylib /usr/local/lib/libhdf5.101.dylib`

or (assuming you've created the necessary dirs):

`ln -s ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/libhdf5.103.dylib ~/anconda3/lib/libhdf5.101.dylib`